# XMLStartlet is not updating package.xml file

Tags: xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I want to create Salesforce Dynamic package.xml file. I followed the process mentioned in this (apexandbeyond.wordpress.com/2017/03/15/dynamic-package-xml-generation/) blog, it is neither updating not inserting dat in xml file. I am trying following way but i doesn't work for me. please help me on this.

```
xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode "/Package/types[name='ApexClass']" --type elem -n members -v "LoginBroker" testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml

xmlstarlet edit --insert /Package -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml
```

Original file: testpackage.xml

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexComponent</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Expected result:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>LoginBroker</members>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit  -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"\
   -u "//x:Package//x:types[x:name[1][text()='ApexClass']]/x:members" \
   -v 'LoginBroker' \
   testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml
```

Comment: This is really helpful but i want the above scenario for iterate in loop. Below is the example for iterating loop. Can you please help this scenario.
 $TYPENAME: ApexClass 
 $ENTITY: LoginBroker

  $TYPENAME: ApexPage 
  $ENTITY: AnnuityVisualizerWrapper
=======================
xmlstarlet edit  -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"\
   -u "//x:Package//x:types[x:name[1][text()=$TYPENAME]]/x:members" \
   -v $ENTITY\
   testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml

Comment: @Saranya I'm not sure I understand your question, but in any event, per SO policy you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: thanks for responding. I posted a new request with detailed description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017095/xmlstartlet-is-not-updating-salesforce-package-xml-file.
please help me here.