# XMLStartlet is not updating salesforce package.xml file

Tags: salesforce, xmlstarlet

I want to create Salesforce Dynamic package.xml file. I followed the process mentioned in this **apexandbeyond.wordpress.com/2017/03/15/dynamic-package-xml-generation/ blog**, it is neither updating not inserting data in xml file. I am trying following way but i doesn't work for me. please help me on this.
Below code is in loop i need update xml file dynamically. Here i am getting modified file dynamically.

git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB -t -r $PREVRSA $LCOMMIT | \
while read -r CFILE; do
    case "$CFILE"
        in
                *.cls*) TYPENAME="ApexClass";;
                *.component*) TYPENAME="ApexComponent";;
                *.page*) TYPENAME="ApexPage";;
                *) TYPENAME="UNKNOWN TYPE";;

```
    esac

    if [[ "$TYPENAME" != "UNKNOWN TYPE" ]]
    then
        echo $TYPENAME "," $ENTITY #example:(ApexClass,TestClass1
                                   #example: ApexClass,Testclass2 
                                   #example: ApexPage,TestPage) # getting values Dynamically

       xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode "/Package/types[name=$TYPENAME]" --type elem -n members -v 
         "$ENTITY" testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml


    fi
```

done

echo Cleaning up Package.xml

xmlstarlet ed -L -i /Package -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" testpackage.xml > edipackage.xml

Original testpackage.xml file:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexComponent</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>TestClass1</members>
<members>TestClass2</members>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>TestPage</members>
<name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace should be defined as follows:

`xml sel -N x=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata   -t -m //x:name -v . -n salesforce.xml`

which returns:

```
ApexClass 
ApexComponent 
ApexPage
```